# how to sum up mm:ss in excel properly - sum() not working?

Tags: excel, datetime, time, sum

I have selected the format for cells as time. But when applying

```
=sum(b1:b40)
```

it produces 00:00

[image: oo]

then "custom format" as [h]:mm for the output cell, but no result.
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What format are the cells in column B, 09:08 is usually 8 minutes past 9am. 00:09:08 would be 9mins and 8 seconds

Comment: the format is mm:ss. it's min and seconds, not hours, it's lesson durations

Comment: So if you select the cell and look in the formula bar, do you see 12:09:08 AM or 09:08:00 AM?  Even if your cell format is mm:ss, you still need to enter the extra 00: at the start.

Comment: If not then use left() to get the first two numbers and right for the last two, then deal with them.

Answer (score 3):

Between your question and your comments, I couldn't figure out if you are trying to count hours and minutes, or minutes and seconds. The solution works in either case.

I drafted an explanation with both possibilities, just in case.

[image: drafted an explanation]

**Here's an explanation if you can't get to the image for whatever reason:**

By default when you SUM time in Excel, it counts time of day + time of day. For instance, 9:00 AM + 11:00 AM would be displayed as 8:00 PM.

What we want is to count AMOUNT of time. In that case 9:00 + 11:00 would be displayed as 20:00.

When counting minutes and seconds, enter the info as 00:mm:ss and format it as `mm:ss`. In the cell you calculate the SUM in, format it as `[mm]:ss` to count AMOUNT of time rather than TIME itself.

When counting hours and minutes, enter the info as hh:mm:00 and format it as `hh:mm`. In the cell you calculate the SUM in, format it as `[hh]:mm` to count AMOUNT of time rather than TIME itself.

If you wanted, you could also count days.

```
dd "days" hh "hours and" mm "minutes"
```